# if else statements to change alert output

Tags: javascript

ok, so I started learning javascript today, and I am making a really simple user input system.

so I am trying to have the name input by the user change the alert output. here is the code

```
var firstName = prompt("What's your name?", "");
alert ( "Welcome, user "+ firstName + "!")

document.write(firstName + " logged on");
```

so this will have all names input have the output be "welcome user (input name)"
and have the document.write be "(input name) is logged on"

I would like to say something if a certian name is input like "you have admin access"
the code i would use is this:

```
var firstName = prompt("What's your first name?", "");
alert ( "Welcome, user "+ firstName + "!")

document.write(firstName + " logged on");
console.log(firstName + " logged on");
if (firstName = "nate"){
    alert ("you now have admin access")
};
```

as you may know, this is wrong. is there any way to do this correctly? if so, what?

Comment: `->` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators

Answer (score 1):

One `=` sign means you are assigning to a variable. And since the value you are assigning is truthy, the if will be executed. To compare two objects use `==` to use type casting or `===` if you want strict typing eg 5 != "5"

Comment: *"And since the assignment is valid, it will always return true and the if will be executed."* Not correct. The result of the assignment expression is the assigned value itself. E.g. the "condition" `if (foo = false)` would never be fulfilled. In this specific case the condition will indeed always be fulfilled, since `"nate"` is a non-empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Replace = with this == if you are comparing two values..

Answer (score 0):

`=` operator is for assignment. You want `==` to compare the values.

Some people might recommend `===` to also check types (in addition to values), but `prompt()` always returns a string and you're comparing it to a string. Know the tools, then choose the best way.

Answer (score 0):

A single `=` is an assignment operator. To do a comparison you need to use `==`.

As you learn more, you might want to look into the difference between `==` & `===`, though it's probably not the most important thing to note now.